# How do I install jqplot in my project?

Tags: javascript, html, jqplot

I'm trying to use jqplot, but when I follow the `http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html` Nothing seems to happen.

When i look at the examples page, and use firefox to look at them, the examples are far different from the Usage.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download jqplot from this site https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/downloads/